# Any package or method to "Group by" in view - Ubunutu(20.04)

Tags: gnome, 20.04, files

I'm quite beginner to Ubuntu. when i view files, all files are mixed up with folders. previously as a windows user, I changed most of explorer window views to "Group by `type` and Sort By `date` and i only found sort option in current Ubuntu. i know  `View -> List` can view as group. but it's not fulfill the needs. is there any ui mod or package or gnome-files alternative to view files in group by?
thank you